# capture output from another CGI program

Tags: perl

I need to capture output from another CGI program which is in the same directory as my perl script.

I tried

```
my $output = `./cgi_name.cgi?param1=some_string&param1=some_string`;
```

but I got an error like param1=some_string&param1=some_string are not valid. the cgi_name.cgi does not support command-line arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `cgi_name.cgi` a Perl script using the [`CGI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) module? Then it can tell whether it is being run from the command-line or through CGI, and in the former case, it will treat command line arguments as key-value pairs.

```
# cgi-or-cli.cgi
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(CGI->new);

$ perl cgi-or-cli.cgi field1=value1 foo=bar
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 '.parameters' => [
                                    'field1',
                                    'foo'
                                  ],
                 'use_tempfile' => 1,
                 '.charset' => 'ISO-8859-1',
                 '.fieldnames' => {},
                 'param' => {
                              'field1' => [
                                            'value1'
                                          ],
                              'foo' => [
                                         'bar'
                                       ]
                            },
                 'escape' => 1
               }, 'CGI' );
```

So it is worth a try to pass your key-value pairs as separate command-line arguments:

```
my $output = `./cgi_name.cgi param1=some_string param1=some_string`;
```

It still might be worth a try even if `cgi_name.cgi` is not a Perl script or does not use the `CGI` module.